# Mozilla Browser (Meta) button issue on closed click popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

i faced this issue may be someone else also find it difficult to read button text

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed and will be corrected in the next production build. The issue arose from not declaring a `[disabled]` color within Magento's Meta theme. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with you, it's happening on Chrome too.

That would be an easy CSS fix:

```
input[type="submit"][disabled], input[type="button"][disabled], button[disabled], .button[disabled], a.button[disabled], a.button[disabled]:visited, .btn[disabled], .btn[disabled]:visited, input[type="submit"]:disabled, input[type="button"]:disabled, button:disabled, .button:disabled, a.button:disabled, a.button:visited:disabled, .btn:disabled, .btn:visited:disabled, input._disabled[type="submit"], input._disabled[type="button"], button._disabled, .button._disabled, a.button._disabled, a.button._disabled:visited, .btn._disabled, .btn._disabled:visited {
    background-color: light-grey;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #717171;
}
```

Rendered result:

[image]

Comment: you make work easy for @Hynes

Comment: @QaisarSatti Haha. I appreciate the help! :D